# What route do I use to refer to the path of the current user's profile? Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, devise, routes

Users of my application upload an avatar when they create their profiles. Here is how I display a small version of their profile picture in the navbar:

```
 <li><%= link_to image_tag current_user.avatar(:nav) %></li>
```

I want that link to to go to the profile page of the current user. Here are my routes:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                  things GET    /things(.:format)              things#index
                         POST   /things(.:format)              things#create
               new_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)          things#new
              edit_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format)     things#edit
                   thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)          things#show
                         PATCH  /things/:id(.:format)          things#update
                         PUT    /things/:id(.:format)          things#update
                         DELETE /things/:id(.:format)          things#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pagess#about
                    root GET    /                              things#index
```

I am currently using Devise for authentication.

Here is my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<li><%= link_to (image_tag current_user.avatar(:nav)), user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
```

You may also be able to get away with just 'current_user' and not 'current_user.id'

Answer (score 2):

From the routes you've provided, your user's profile would be `users#show`.  So the path you're looking for should be `user_path`.

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
    ...
  end
end
```

Then in `app/views/users/show.html.erb` you show the user's profile information.

Comment: It solved that error, but it led me to this one:

`No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: @DylanRichards, the show action requires a parameter `id` which is the id of the user's whose profile page you want to visit.  Use it as `user_path(current_user)` or `user_path(id: current_user.id)`.

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer. I have opted to use `user_path(current_user). Now this error appears:

`undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "/users/Delacram":String`

Delacram is the username of the current user.

Comment: I am unsure why you are getting username there, but if you'd like to use `username` then you could do `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])`.  Make sure to use the appropriate key in your `params` hash for `username`.

Comment: Could you post what didn't work and your error log.  Did you verify the contents of the `params` hash?